# Plot 2D histogram data with pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a binned statistic, as one would get from [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html). Basically, that means I have edge values and within-bin data. This also means I *cannot* (to my knowledge) use `plt.hist2d`. Here's a code snippet to generate the sort of data I might need to plot:

```
import numpy as np
x_edges = np.arange(6)
y_edges = np.arange(6)
bin_values = np.random.randn(5, 5)
```

One would imagine that I could use `pcolormesh` for this, but the issue is that `pcolormesh` does not allow for bin edge values. The following will only plot the values in bins 1 through 4. The 5th value is excluded, since while pcolormesh "knows" that the value at 4.0 is some value, there is no later value to plot, so the width of the 5th bin is zero.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.broadcast_arrays(x_edges[:5, None], y_edges[None, :5])

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, bin_values)
plt.show()
```

I *can* get around this with an ugly hack by adding an additional set of values equal to the last values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.broadcast_arrays(x_edges[:, None], y_edges[None, :])
dummy_bin_values = np.zeros([6, 6])
dummy_bin_values[:5, :5] = bin_values
dummy_bin_values[5, :] = dummy_bin_values[4, :]
dummy_bin_values[:, 5] = dummy_bin_values[:, 4]

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, dummy_bin_values)
plt.show()
```

However, this *is* an ugly hack. Is there any cleaner way to plot 2D histogram data with bin edge values? "No" is possibly the correct answer, but convince me that's the case if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand the problem with any of the two options. So here is simly a code which uses both, numpy histogrammed data with pcolormesh, as well as simply `plt.hist2d`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_edges = np.arange(6)
y_edges = np.arange(6)
data = np.random.rand(340,2)*5

### using numpy.histogram2d
bin_values,_,__ = np.histogram2d(data[:,0],data[:,1],bins=(x_edges, y_edges) )
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_edges,y_edges)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.set_title("numpy.histogram2d \n + plt.pcolormesh")
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, bin_values.T)

### using plt.hist2d
ax2.set_title("plt.hist2d")
ax2.hist2d(data[:,0],data[:,1],bins=(x_edges, y_edges))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course this would equally work with `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`.

Comment: You're right. The core of my mis-understanding was not realizing that you can pass in X and Y to pcolormesh that have dimensions of length one greater than Z.